# error en la clase modelo

Tags: mvc, php8

Estoy tratando de traer la información de la BD y mostrarla pero al querer incluir la clase del controlador me da error al llamar la clase MODELO pero si hago un insert normal el controlador si me incluye la clase MODELO pero al mostrar los datos no.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 namespace controller;
 ini_set ( 'display_errors' , 1 );
 ini_set ( 'display_startup_errors' , 1 );
 error_reporting ( E_ALL );
 include_once ( '../../models/registerUserModel.php' );
 class MostrarUsuarios extends registerUserModel
 {
    
    static public function ctrMostrarUsuarios(){
        
        $tabla = 'usuarios';
        
        $res = MostrarUsuarios ::mdlMostrarUsuarios ( $tabla );
        MostrarUsuarios ::ctrSwitch ( $res );
        return $res;
    }
    
 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intenta con: include_once ( '././models/registerUserModel.php' );

Comment: tampoco me funciona.

Comment: a ver creo que ya vi como esta, al parecer (corrigeme si me euivoco), el error esta en el archivo **MostrarUsuarios.php** dentro de la carpeta **controler** y quieres utilizar el archivo **registerUsrModel.php** dentro de la carpeta **models** entonces tendrias que utilizar './' para regresar una carpeta y despues entrar a **models** a ver intenta con esta 'include_once ( './models/registerUserModel.php' );'

Comment: ya lo coregi tuve que poner un USE en la vista y poner un namespace en el controller